# Load partial view multiple times on click of a button

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor

Background: I have 2 entities, Course and Module. A course can have many modules. On the page where you update/add modules, it's basically an update page of the course where each module has a partial page rendered in an accordion. See screenshot:

[image]

I have this to populate existing Modules:

```
@foreach (var module in Model.Modules)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Module/_Update.cshtml", (RocketLabs.Models.Module)module);
}
```

How do I add Partial Renders (with new models) every time the Add Module is clicked?

Any piece of advise would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you taking a look at the [`Editing a Variable Length List`](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) article from Steven Sanderson where he illustrates how you could use an AJAX request to a server side partial to add new rows dynamically. The idea here is to subscribe to the click event of the Add button and trigger an AJAX request to a controller action that will return a new partial containing a blank row to be edited.

And if you want a pure client side solution, he also wrote [`an article`](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/) where the same could be achieved with knockoutjs for example without any AJAX requests to add new entries to the list.